# Is there a way to specify in Jenkinsfile/Makefile which python version is used?

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, makefile

I am putting our Python scripts in our Jenkins pipeline and 1 of our scripts if causing me a lot of headaches. I'm using a Jenkinsfile with Make commands. I have a Makefile with commands in it. Now the code itself uses removesuffix and removeprefix, which are python 3.9 and higher but our devops team is reluctant to change the python version in our Jenkins agents.

Now I have a way of course to specify from command line which python version to use (simply python3 or python3.9 etc). But now I also want to run coverage on my unit tests to be picked up by sonar. so I have created the following in my Makefile:

```
    coverage run -m unittest discover -v
    coverage xml
    mkdir coverage-reports || True
    cp coverage.xml coverage-reports/coverage-report.xml
```

Which works perfectly as well, except when testing paths hitting the "3.9 code", at which time Jenkins fails.

I tried the obvious thing with `python3.9 coverage run -m discover -v` but it doesn't work.
Also tried in in the requirements.txt - no success

My question is. Is there a way to specify per stage(jenkins) which python version to use?

Comment: The usual way to do this is to have a configuration step where you install the Python versions you want, possibly outside of your Makefile or Jenkins flow; then use whatever was configured. A common mechanism for Python is to use `tox` or `nox`, though there are other popular alternatives (`pyenv` comes to mind for installing and managing arbitrary Python versions).

Comment: Thanks tripleee. I already have the option to run a certain version (I have multiple versions in my Jenkins agents). The problem is that when running the unit tests from my Jenkinsfile I call it via coverage run, which will trigger the "standard" version of the agent (3.6) If I call python3.9 -m unittest it runs all tests correctly but without coverage so sonar cannot collect the details. 

I was hoping for a very simple solution where I can add the python3.9 prefix to the coverage call